# Are two crossfire bridges necessary

Tags: crossfire

I have two Gigabyte HD4850's on a P5Q pro. The manual says 2 bridges are necessary but some fora sayit isn't. Can anyone clear this out?

What's the benefit you get from two bridges over having only one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two bridges assure more stability. But the real meaning of the second crossfire is to add a third card.

Also provides more stability in benchmarks (second link)

Refs:

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/309640-33-crossfire-bridges

http://www.xtremesystems.org/forums/showthread.php?235626-1-crossfire-bridge-vs-2-crossfire-bridges

Comment: Can you add a reference for this? Is there some official source that has this information?

Comment: There, I can't add more references because of the limited reputation.

Comment: Thanks @SeinOxygen for adding more info! You'll get the ability to add more links soon.

Answer (score 0):

- Intel chipset + HD 4850s + 1 crossfire bridge = yes to crossfire (some of the earlier HD xxxx require 2).
- Nvidia chipset = crossfire not possible.
- AMD chipset = crossfireX (no bridge needed depends on chipset & GPU) or crossfire with a bridge is a yes.
- 890gx,890fx, 990x or 990fx = crossfire faster and the 990s will SLI too.

Last but not least, there is asymetrical crossfire with an AMD APU (Llano) and specific GPUs.